# compile error ADF-jdeveloper

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have error, when i try compile project

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
        <markers xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/110000ide-markers">
           <list n="markers">
              <hash>
                 <value n="code" v="0"/>
                 <value n="column" v="33"/>
                 <value n="description" v="Error(15,33): expecting '}', found ')' @ line 15, column 33."/>
                 <list n="events">
                    <hash>
                       <value n="event-description" v="Rebuild AgreementsTab.jpr"/>
                       <value n="event-id" v="f873829b-b9ed-43b9-bebd-87b1f37a7b34"/>
                       <value n="event-timestamp" v="1500964315640"/>
                    </hash>
                 </list>
                 <value n="id" v="682fb1ce-a184-4887-b32c-79af1c9c3453"/>
                 <value n="lastUpdated" v="1500964325979"/>
                 <value n="line" v="15"/>
                 <url n="markableURL" path="../../../JDeveloper/mywork/agreements_tab_rebuild/AgreementsApp.jws"/>
                 <value n="severity" v="0"/>
                 <value n="timestamp" v="1500964325870"/>
                 <value n="type" v="oracle.jdeveloper.compiler.CompilerProblemMarker"/>
              </hash>
           </list>
        </markers>
```

.jws file don't have ) and What reason this error?

```
 15 Line:  <value n="oracle.adfdtinternal.model.ide.security.extension.AdfSecurityMigrator" v="11.1.1.1.0.13"/>
```

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar kind of error in my application.

```
Error(17,19): expecting ')', found '=' @ line 17, column 19.
```

But, later I found that there was an syntax error in one of the Groovy expressions.

So, you can check the `*.bcs` files for the error in your application.

I hope this helps you.